# How to send objects through TcpClient and TcpListener?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Ok so i am developing a really simple multiplayer game in .NET that will be played on LAN.

The Problem is that in order for the game to work i have to send the whole object. Previously i have made a chat system by using `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` to send messages. However i am not sure that sending objects is possible or even desirable in this case.

While searching on SO somebody suggested using serialization. However upon some research i discovered that all classes whose objects are referenced by the serialized object must also be serialized. Now the object i must sent contains quite a few reference to other objects. Meaning to use serialization i must infact serialize almost every class in the program.

Now i am not sure which approach to use. `TcpClient` or serialize or something else ?

Comment: You need to design a *wire protocol* for your client and server: a set of rules to not only serialize (the necessary parts of) objects and get them back at the other end, but also rules that make the receiver able to parse the data coming in from the server. This is necessary because TCP is a stream protocol and does not have the concept of "self-contained messages".

Comment: not sure i am following you

Comment: Most likely you need to read articles instead of asking a question here, there are too many things to explain. Start with simple examples like sending maps of values and leave objects for later.

Answer (score 0):

You can send objects by creating a WCF project. You will need to amend objects so that they are datacontracts, but it can make life much easier since you don't need to do any further processing after you've called the webservice.